# Sourcing in Rprofile.site: How to find the location of the sourced file

Tags: r, rprofile

I have a "copy deployed" installation of R with no R-specific environment variables set.

I want to source a file from within `Rprofile.site`:

```
source("how/to/find/this/file/my_settings.R")
```

Where could I place my `my_settings.R` file so that it can be found from within `Rprofile.site` no matter in which path `Rprofile.site` is installed?

BTW: I want to avoid an absolute path to `my_settings.R` this would work indeed. I'd prefer to use the same folder as `Rprofile.site` or a path relative to it to support copy deployment of R.

**Edit 1: The problem is that `getwd` is always different depending on the current folder from which you start R**

Comment: if you type `print(getwd())` just where you plan to write your `source` instruction you should get this location

Comment: I have already tried `getwd()` but it seems the path is not stable (at least not within RStudio - it depends on the currently opened project if you restart the R session)

Comment: you've tried to write this line into your Rprofile file or after the session is opened ? If it's the former it means the project directory is set before Rprofile is read. You could also use `.libPaths()[1]` or `.libPaths()[2]`, assuming you don't plan to mess with those later. On my computer I could put a file in `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/library` and source it with `source(paste0(.libPaths()[2],"/my_file.R"))`

Comment: If have put `getwd` into `Rprofile.site` and started a new R sessions and new RStudio session. In fact `getwd` always returns the current path of command prompt (R session) or the RStudio project root folder. `libPaths()` could be possible workaround but I would prefer to store the sourced file in the same folder als `Rprofile.site`

Comment: `source(paste0(.libPaths()[2],"/etc/my_file.R"))` then ? If your Rprofile isn't there for some reason, you can use whatever relative path you need from libPath and get to your file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use absolute paths and that your working directory is not stable, one way is to use `.libPaths` or `.Library`.

By default your `Rprofile` should be in directory `paste0(.Library,"/../etc/")` or `paste0(.libPaths()[2],"/etc/")`  so you can put your file there and source it with :

```
source(paste0(.Library,"/../etc/my_settings.R")) 
source(paste0(.libPaths()[2],"/etc/my_settings.R"))
```

As far as I understand the first option is stable (I don't think one can change the value of `.Library`).

If you use the second option just make sure that if in the future you alter your `.libPaths()` you do it after sourcing your file.

See `?.libPaths` for more info on default folders.

Comment: Note: This is a good solution for Windows, on Linux the `Rprofile.site` is located in `/etc/R` so searching the file relative to the library path is not possible (but also not necessary if the the absolute path is always the same!).